# Projection, Queries missing in Orchard 1.4.2

Tags: orchardcms

I can't see the queries section the dashboard, neither can I see that as a part of Projection Page.

Has anything changed?

In logs, there is one error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu.Drivers.BreadcrumbsPartDriver.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Display>b__4()
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClassd.<ContentShape>b__c(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\OrchardWebsite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 108
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass13.<ContentShapeImplementation>b__12(BuildShapeContext ctx) in C:\OrchardWebsite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 116
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.ApplyImplementation(BuildShapeContext context, String displayType) in C:\OrchardWebsite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 37
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.Apply(BuildDisplayContext context) in C:\OrchardWebsite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 21
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClassa.<BuildDisplay>b__9(IContentPartDriver driver) in C:\OrchardWebsite\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\Coordinators\ContentPartDriverCoordinator.cs:line 49
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in C:\OrchardWebsite\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's still there. Something else must be going on, such as a version mismatch causing an exception when loading the module. Did you check your app_data\logs folder?

Comment: There is only one. I have updated my question with the error..it is not related with Projection though, I think.

Comment: Is this a migration from a previous version?

Comment: No, it is not. I downloaded the latest version and installed it.

Comment: What other modules did you install?

Comment: None other than Advanced Navigation Module. I get this error as soon as I install it.

Comment: Then you should contact the author of that module. There is a contact form on each gallery module's page. Piotr will answer.

Comment: His site is down, but I will try and contact him later. Thanks Bertrand! I installed a fresh download, and projection seems to work now. Got the same error though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found out the **projector module** was disabled. I don't know why it was disabled but it made sense enabling it.

Comment: Hi Willem! You are right - this issue also occurs when the Projector module is disabled. Although, at the time this error occurred, the Projector module was enabled. But yeah, good note to other devs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Queries not showing up in the Dashboard. Disabling the Autoroute module and enabling it again worked for me.