# Queries missing under 1.5.1

Tags: orchardcms

Similar to [Projection, Queries missing in Orchard 1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877904/projection-queries-missing-in-orchard-1-4-2) except that Projections is displaying on the the dashboard. But Queries doesn't.

One troubleshooting step was disable/re-enable the Autoroute. No joy. I'd installed Advanced Menu originally - I've since disabled it but haven't found instructions on a deeper uninstall. Is that posted anywhere?

thx

Comment: Look at your app_data\logs folder.

Comment: Didn't see anything related to 'Queries' there.

Comment: What about something related to Orchard.Projections? I'm also confused about why you disabled and re-enabled Autoroute, which has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Just following the path reported to have worked by the post in the original link. I'm not in a position to step into each log file individually - there's probably some global search strategy but until something breaks again I'm good. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off all non-native modules, restarted the site (via IIS), deleted _backup folder (held only the Advanced Menu module). Some one or combination of those actions restored 'Queries'.